# Find Range of Values in Matlab Figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to find range of values between two points in Matlab figure. I made this figure

[image]

using `plot()`. Now this figure will be used as input and in output I want values between point `A` and `B`.

**Note:** Point `A` and `B` mentioned in figure are using photoshop that are not part of plot, its just to make the question clear.

Comment: You got the Data which you used for the `plot()` right? And you want to know the x-values of A,B, so that you can use them as input for another function? Is `A` allways `0` and how is `B` characterized? Is it the Minimum between the two maxima? Or is it a fixed value... We need more information to help you. ALSO you should try to tell us what you tried so far, where you are stuck, etc...

Comment: Yes I have Data that i used in PLOT(); I want to know Values of X(time) and Y coordinates between A and B point. But Problem is A is always Starting Point on Graph. But B can be Changed every time i will execute the code. 

Its Part of Research project. I draw any thing on Figure 1 (Canvas) then from that Drawn thing output is this Figure( figure that is Posted Above).

Comment: If that is not Possible. then Other Option could be. Values Between A(starting Point) and First Minima. That might be Use Full for me too.

Comment: Starting point is quite easy just get the minimum of your x-data. Even better is to sort your data. For the "other" option check out the help section for `differentiate()` (just type: "help differentiate" into your command window). You could do sth like this: sort your data according to x-value. Compute the differentiate of the "function". Search for the minimum (before it has to be negative and behind it has to be positive, while the minimum itself is zero). Then find the index of it and use `x(1:index), y(1:index)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hc=get(gca,'children');
data=get(hc,{'xdata','ydata'});

t=data{1};

y=data{2};

tA=250;tB=1000; %tA is starting Point and tB is the last point of data as ur figure

yinterval=y(t>=tA & t<=tB);

display(yinterval);
```